salesforce cli via npm installation not working - Getting error: sf is not a recognised command
I have windows machine from my company which is locked down. I managed to install node via company portal and tied to install salesforce cli using the documentation provided by salesforce. The command I am using is
npm install @salesforce/cli --global.

I don't get an error but when i type sf version, i get the error:
'sf' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
I have tried running the installation command again but have similar result. Do i need to make any changes to path variable or is something else I am missing.

Does it have sf.exe in the installation path?

Try to look for the node modules
find ~ -name "SF" or  find ~ -name "sfdx"
set the PATH variable and try again
PATH=/root/cli/sf/bin:$PATH
